# Need to dynamically get data from a url and return a scaffold with ListView Builder

Tags: flutter, listview, dynamic, setstate, scaffold

Currently, I need to go back and reopen the page to get new data. I am not able to successfully make the dynamic component. Some people suggested using setState() but I am not able to put a scaffold inside it. If I try to setState() the uri parsing line I get stuck loading without any list being displayed. If you could guide me about how to achieve the dynamic component of the app it would be great. Thanks in advance!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert' as convert;

class LiveData extends StatefulWidget {
const LiveData({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<LiveData> createState() => _LiveDataState();
}

class _LiveDataState extends State<LiveData> {

static const color = Color(0xFFfdecbd);
static const boxbgcolor = Color(0xFFfff8e5);

var data = [];
getFeedbackFromSheet() async {

var raw = await http.get(Uri.parse(
    "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyqH82oPAYxw0rXhGa3DcpjaOeL2hjnJP-Ia7VGZEimS8HjgPOLhmXqqYRK1qW0EfUT/exec"));

var jsonFeedback = convert.jsonDecode(raw.body);
setState(() {
  data = jsonFeedback;
});
//print('this is json Feedback $jsonFeedback');
}

@override
void initState() {
getFeedbackFromSheet();
super.initState();
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: color,
  body: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: data.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      var feedback = data[data.length-1- index];
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Card(
          color: boxbgcolor,
          elevation: 5,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text("Date : " + feedback["Date"].toString()),
              subtitle: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text("Soil Temperature : " +
                      feedback["Soil Temperature"].toString()),
                  Text("Temperature : " +
                      feedback["Temperature"].toString()),
                  Text("Humidity : " + feedback["Humidity"].toString()),
                  Text("Soil Moisture : " +
                      feedback["Soil Moisture"].toString()),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to keep your widget up to date with the latest data is to refresh periodically.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    getFeedbackFromSheet();
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 10), (_) => getFeedbackFromSheet());
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use RefreshIndicator to refresh data**

RefreshIndicator is a widget in Flutter that supports Material's swipe-to-refresh. It works by showing a circular progress indicator when the child's Scrollable is overscrolled. If the user ends the scroll and the indicator has been dragged far enough, it will call onRefresh.

```
RefreshIndicator(
  onRefresh: getFeedbackFromSheet,
  child: ListView.builder(
    ...
  ),
 )
```